# Cloud Storage guarda mi archivo pero pesa 0 bytes Node, adonis

Tags: javascript, nodejs, google-cloud-storage, adonisjs

Estoy intentando subir archivos pdf a google cloud no obstante a pesar de todo lo que intento el archivo sigue pesando 0 bytes, creo yo lo tengo casi todo resuelto, estoy utilizando adonis Js, estoy en proceso de probar el desactivar el body parser y hacer el request manualmente pero dudo que ese sea el problema...

```js
        const gc = await new Storage({
          projectId: GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT_ID,
          keyFilename: GOOGLE_CLOUD_KEYFILE,
        })

        const bucked = gc.bucket('rootbusco')
        const file = bucked.file(cv.stream.filename)

         const stream = await cv.stream.pipe(file.createWriteStream({
          resumable: false,
          gzip: true,
          metadata: {
            contentType: cv.stream.headers['content-type']
          }
        }))
        console.log(cv)
        stream.end(cv.stream.data);
```

EDITO: Acabo de concluir el proceso de desactivar el Body parser y hacer el request manualmente y funcionó

Comment: El código va como texto por favor, anexo a eso ¿qué versión de adonis estás usando?

Comment: Perdona es que intentando resolver el problema terminé haciendo una sopa de letras y solo tenia esa captura de ayer, estoy utilizando adonis 4.1

Comment: Ya probaste esta guía: https://medium.com/striaco/uploading-files-to-google-cloud-storage-in-adonisjs-12487cf37d18